# Back Up My SQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, backup, database-backups

Hello everyone I am pretty new to php. I am trying to create a back up of my sql database and I want the back up to run on php server at the click of a button. I found some templates the issues I am having and it may be due to the wrong templates are: On most of the templates I don't where I should enter the information that is needed to make it work, for ex( host, dbname) etc another issue is I don't know if that's the only part of the code that needs to be changed. If someone could help me find a backup template and tell me step by step how to get my database to export as a file I would greatly appreciate it!sq

Comment: Can you use `exec();`? try `exec('pwd');` to check it.

Comment: If you have php available, why don't you simply install phpmyadmin? Gives you loads of valuable features, allows to dump databases and simply works.

Comment: I am currently using phpmyadmin but I want to run the back up from the web not from with in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to call [mysqldump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), a backup utility program that's bundled with every MySQL database. Pass the folder you would like the file (it will be a .sql file) to be put, and you can simply download or ftp it from there. 
 
A simpler option is to install [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and you can use it to backup any database and table. 
 
Hope this helps.